# Can I file my 2019 taxes electronically if I already sent them by mail?

Tags: united-states, taxes, covid-19

I put my 2019 taxes in the mail in early March, before everything shut down. Checking the IRS website, it doesn't seem like my taxes have been processed, and I know they have stopped processing paper tax returns.

I would not be eligible for the stimulus payment by my 2018 income, but I would be by my 2019 income. So I'm anxious to get my 2019 taxes processed, so I can receive the stimulus check.

Am I going to mess something up if I file electronically at this point, and then at some point in the future they process my paper taxes?

Comment: I'm not certain what would happen, but they recently did _say_ you should not duplicate-efile: https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/irs-operations-during-covid-19-mission-critical-functions-continue . Sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the [IRS guidance during COVID-19](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/irs-operations-during-covid-19-mission-critical-functions-continue):

https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/irs-operations-during-covid-19-mission-critical-functions-continue

> Paper Tax Returns: All taxpayers should file electronically through
>   their tax preparer, tax software provider or IRS Free File if
>   possible. The IRS is not currently able to process individual paper
>   tax returns. If you already have filed via paper but it has not yet
>   been processed, do not file a second tax return or write to the IRS to
>   inquire about the status of your return or your economic impact
>   payment. Paper returns will be processed   once processing centers are
>   able to reopen. This year, more than 90% of taxpayers have filed
>   electronically.

It appears that you are out of luck. They are asking you to wait for them to process your paper form.

They are trying to avoid having to decide which form is the correct form. They are also trying to avoid having to determine if one of the returns is fraudulent.

Comment: Thank you, I was struggling to find this information. Not what I was hoping for, but thank you for tracking that down.